# Google Analytics Integration

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We are going to develop an ecommerce site.

We are planning to integrate with Google Analytics for Tracking the sales.

But We would like to show our Dealers about how many customers visited the website, how many of them purchased, visiots by country, source and some of data that is show in GA dashboard.

Is there any API available to show GA data and graphs in Dealer Dashboard or ?

Comment: This could be accomplished with the GA API in conjunction with a charting API such as Google Visualizations.  Additionally check out our 3rd party Reporting Tool: http://www.embeddedanalytics.com/embeddedanalyticsforagencies.html (disclosure: I work with them).  Our "Agency" version was developed precisely for this purpose.  The service can work in situations where each "dealer" has their own analytics account.  Or where you have one master account and differentiate among dealers via custom variables.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a comprehensive suite of APIs for reporting.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/

Comment: Thanks Paul. Among that which one suits more? Shall we try with Embed API?

Comment: It's difficult to advise me without a full understanding of your business requirements.

Comment: For our customers(seller) we want to show the GA on their profile (seller interface) which shows the info about like how many visitors visited their product page, traffic, etc...

Comment: Why not just have them register for their own GA code and embed that on their seller page using the standard GA embed techniques?